# Type of precision

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, precision

Precision is obtained below by using keras library:

```
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
          loss='mse',
          metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Precision()])
```

What type of precision calculated by sklearn is equal to the precision calculated by keras?

```
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average=???)
```

1. macro
2. micro
3. weighted
4. none

What happens when you set the zero_division to be 1 as in below?:

```
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None, zero_division=1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR;** Default is `binary` for binary classification and `micro` for multi-class classification. Other average types such as `None` and `macro` can also be achieved with minor modification as explained below.

---

This should give you some clarity on the differences between `tf.keras.Precision()` and `sklearn.metrics.precision_score()`. Let's compare different scenarios.

**Scenario 1: Binary classification**

For binary classification, your y_true and y_pred are 0,1 and 0-1 respectively. The implementation for both is quite straight forward.

> Sklearn documentation: Only report results for the class specified by pos_label. This is applicable only if targets (y_{true,pred}) are binary.

```
#Binary classification

from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = [0,1,1,1]
y_pred = [1,0,1,1]

print('sklearn precision: ',precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='binary'))
#Only report results for the class specified by pos_label. 
#This is applicable only if targets (y_{true,pred}) are binary.

m = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
m.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
print('tf.keras precision:',m.result().numpy())
```

```
sklearn precision:  0.6666666666666666
tf.keras precision: 0.6666667
```

**Scenario 2: Multi-class classification (global precision)**

Here you are working with multi-class labels but you are not bothered about how the Precision is for each individual class. You simply want a global set of TP and FP to calculate a total precision score. In `sklearn` this is set by the parameter `micro`, while in `tf.keras` this is the default setting for `Precision()`

> Sklearn documentation: Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.

```
#Multi-class classification (global precision)

#3 classes, 6 samples
y_true = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
y_pred = [[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]

print('sklearn precision: ',precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro'))
#Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.

m.reset_states()
m = tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
m.update_state(y_true, y_pred)
print('tf.keras precision:',m.result().numpy())
```

```
sklearn precision:  0.3333333333333333
tf.keras precision: 0.33333334
```

**Scenario 3: Multi-class classification (binary precision for each label)**

You are interested in this scenario if you want to know the precision for each individual class. In `sklearn` this is done by setting the `average` parameter to `None`, while in `tf.keras` you will have to instantiate the object for each individual class separately using `class_id`.

> Sklearn documentation: If None, the scores for each class are returned.

```
#Multi-class classification (binary precision for each label)

#3 classes, 6 samples
y_true = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
y_pred = [[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]

print('sklearn precision: ',precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None))
#If None, the scores for each class are returned.

#For class 0
m0 = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=0)
m0.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

#For class 1
m1 = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=1)
m1.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

#For class 2
m2 = tf.keras.metrics.Precision(class_id=2)
m2.update_state(y_true, y_pred)

mm = [m0.result().numpy(), m1.result().numpy(), m2.result().numpy()]

print('tf.keras precision:',mm)
```

```
sklearn precision:  [0.66666667 0.         0.        ]
tf.keras precision: [0.6666667, 0.0, 0.0]
```

**Scenario 4: Multi-class classification (Average of individual binary scores)**

Once you have calculated the individual precision for each class, you may want to take the average score (or weighted average). In `sklearn`, a simple average of the individual scores is taken by setting the parameter `average` to `macro`. In `tf.keras` you can get the same result by taking an average of the individual precisions as calculated in the scenario above.

> Sklearn documentation: Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean.

```
#Multi-class classification (Average of individual binary scores)

#3 classes, 6 samples
y_true = [[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1],[1,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,1]]
y_pred = [[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,0],[0,1,0]]

print('sklearn precision (Macro): ',precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro'))
print('sklearn precision (Avg of None):' ,np.average(precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None)))

print(' ')

print('tf.keras precision:',np.average(mm)) #mm is list of individual precision scores
```

```
sklearn precision (Macro):  0.2222222222222222
sklearn precision (Avg of None):  0.2222222222222222
 
tf.keras precision: 0.22222222
```

**NOTE:** Remember, with `sklearn`, you have models that are predicting labels directly and the `precision_score` is a standalone method. Therefore, it can operate directly on a list of labels for predicted and actuals. However, `tf.keras.Precision()` is a metric that has to be applied over a binary or multi-class dense output. It will NOT be able to work with labels directly. You will have to give it an n-length array for each sample, where n is the number of classes/output dense nodes.

Hope this clarifies how the 2 are different in various scenarios. Please find more details in the [sklearn documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) and the [tf.keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/Precision).

---

**Your second question -**

As per the sklearn documentation,

```
zero_division - “warn”, 0 or 1, default=”warn”
#Sets the value to return when there is a zero division. If set to “warn”, #this acts as 0, but warnings are also raised.
```

This is an exception handling flag. During the calculation of the score, if there comes a time when it encounters a `divide by zero`, it will consider it to be equal to zero and warn. Else, set it to 1, if set explicitly as 1.