# Appropriate f1 scoring for highly imbalanced data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, imbalanced-data

I am confused with three different f1 computation. Which f1 scoring I should use for a severely imbalanced data? I am working on a severely imbalanced binary classification.

```
‘f1’
‘f1_micro’
‘f1_macro’
‘f1_weighted’
```

Also, I want to add `balanced_accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred, adjusted=True)` in `balanced_accuracy` scoring argument. How can I incorporate this in my code?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from imblearn.metrics import geometric_mean_score
X, y = load_breast_cancer(return_X_y=True)

gm_scorer = make_scorer(geometric_mean_score, greater_is_better=True)
scores = cross_validate(LogisticRegression(max_iter=100000),X,y, cv=5,scoring={'gm_scorer': gm_scorer, 'F1': 'f1', 'Balanced Accuracy': 'balanced_accuracy'}
)
scores
```

Comment: f1_micro is global f1 score, if you want to worry about how f1 is affected by each class (with imbalance), you would want to use `f1_macro` or `f1_weighted`. More details in my answer below.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

`f1_micro` is for global f1, while `f1_macro` takes the individual class-wise f1 and then takes an average.

Its similar to `precision` and its micro, macro, weights parameters in `sklearn`. Do check the SO post [Type of precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279074/type-of-precision/65279715#65279715) where I explain the difference. f1 score is basically a way to consider both precision and recall at the same time.

Also, as per [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html#sklearn.metrics.f1_score):

> 'micro': Calculate metrics globally by counting the total true positives, false negatives and false positives.
>
> 'macro': Calculate metrics for each label, and find their unweighted mean. This does not take label imbalance into account.
>
> 'weighted': Calculate metrics for each label, and find their average weighted by support (the number of true instances for each label). This alters ‘macro’ to account for label imbalance; it can result in an F-score that is not between precision and recall.

For your specific case, you might want to use `f1_macro` (unweighted average of class-wise f1) or `f1_weighted` (weights average of class-wise f1), as `f1_micro` will high the class-wise contribution to the f1.

Comment: I got a pretty strange result when I used f1_weighted measure. I posted a separate question to see the differences of popular scoring metrics that are used in imbalanced data domain.