# How to find the value of precision and recall using the Confusion Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to find the precision and recall for the confusion matrix given below, but an error occurred. How would I accomplish it using Numpy and Sklearn?

```
array([[748,   0,   4,   5,   1,  16,   9,   4,   8,   0],
       [  0, 869,   6,   5,   2,   2,   2,   5,  12,   3],
       [  6,  19, 642,  33,  13,   7,  16,  15,  31,   6],
       [  5,   3,  30, 679,   2,  44,   1,  12,  23,  12],
       [  4,   7,   9,   2, 704,   5,  10,   8,   7,  43],
       [  5,   6,  10,  39,  11, 566,  18,   4,  33,  10],
       [  6,   5,  17,   2,   5,  12, 737,   2,   9,   3],
       [  5,   7,   8,  18,  14,   2,   0, 752,   5,  42],
       [  7,  15,  34,  28,  12,  29,   6,   4, 600,  18],
       [  4,   6,   6,  16,  21,   4,   0,  50,   8, 680]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: The reason you are getting an error is that this is NOT a confusion matrix. Its dimensions are 10X9. A confusion matrix would always be a square matrix 9X9 or 10X10 in this case.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal thank you for pointing that out, I made a change in the question.

Comment: What type of precision are you looking at? Macro, Micro? Check this for more clarity https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279074/type-of-precision/65279715#65279715

Comment: As I understand, you are trying to calculate precision and recall values directly from a confusion matrix, instead of using `y_true` and `y_pred` with a sklearn API. If that is the case, I have elaborated on how you derive precision and recall on a confusion matrix directly and some general knowledge on macro and micro metrics. Do check my answer and let me know if that solves your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already recommended by someone else, you can directly calulate over `y_actual` and y_predicted`using`sklearn.metrics`with`precision_score`and`recall_score`to calculate what you need. Read more here for [precision](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) and [recall](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.recall_score.html) scores.

But, IIUC, you are looking to do the same, directly, with a confusion matrix. Here is how you calculate precision and recall using the confusion matrix directly.

---

1. First I'll demonstrate by using a dummy example, showing results from SKLEARN API and then calculating them directly.

> NOTE: There are 2 types of precision and recall that are generally calculated -
>
> - Micro precision: All TP across all classes summed and divided by the TP+FP
> - Macro precision: Calculate TP/TP+FP for each class separately, and then take an average (ignorning nans)
> - You can find more details on [types of precision (and recall) here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65279074/type-of-precision/65279715#65279715).

I show both the methods for your understanding below -

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, precision_score, recall_score

####################################################
#####Using SKLEARN API on TRUE & PRED Labels########
####################################################

y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
y_pred = [0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]
confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)

precision_micro = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average="micro")
precision_macro = precision_score(y_true, y_pred, average="macro")
recall_micro = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average='micro')
recall_macro = recall_score(y_true, y_pred, average="macro")

print("Sklearn API")
print("precision_micro:", precision_micro)
print("precision_macro:", precision_macro)
print("recall_micro:", recall_micro)
print("recall_macro:", recall_macro)

####################################################
####Calculating directly from confusion matrix######
####################################################

cf = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
TP = cf.diagonal()

precision_micro = TP.sum()/cf.sum()
recall_micro = TP.sum()/cf.sum()

#NOTE: The sum of row-wise sums of a matrix = sum of column-wise sums of a matrix = sum of all elements of a matrix
#Therefore, the micro-precision and micro-recall is mathematically the same for a multi-class problem.


precision_macro = np.nanmean(TP/cf.sum(0))
recall_macro = np.nanmean(TP/cf.sum(1))

print("")
print("Calculated:")
print("precision_micro:", precision_micro)
print("precision_macro:", precision_macro)
print("recall_micro:", recall_micro)
print("recall_macro:", recall_macro)
```

```
Sklearn API
precision_micro: 0.6666666666666666
precision_macro: 0.8333333333333334
recall_micro: 0.6666666666666666
recall_macro: 0.7777777777777777

Calculated:
precision_micro: 0.6666666666666666
precision_macro: 0.8333333333333334
recall_micro: 0.6666666666666666
recall_macro: 0.7777777777777777
```

---

2. Now that I have proven that the definitions behind the APIs work as described, let's calculate precision and recall for your case.

```
cf = [[748,   0,   4,   5,   1,  16,   9,   4,   8,   0],
      [  0, 869,   6,   5,   2,   2,   2,   5,  12,   3],
      [  6,  19, 642,  33,  13,   7,  16,  15,  31,   6],
      [  5,   3,  30, 679,   2,  44,   1,  12,  23,  12],
      [  4,   7,   9,   2, 704,   5,  10,   8,   7,  43],
      [  5,   6,  10,  39,  11, 566,  18,   4,  33,  10],
      [  6,   5,  17,   2,   5,  12, 737,   2,   9,   3],
      [  5,   7,   8,  18,  14,   2,   0, 752,   5,  42],
      [  7,  15,  34,  28,  12,  29,   6,   4, 600,  18],
      [  4,   6,   6,  16,  21,   4,   0,  50,   8, 680]]

cf = np.array(cf)
TP = cf.diagonal()

precision_micro = TP.sum()/cf.sum()
recall_micro = TP.sum()/cf.sum()


precision_macro = np.nanmean(TP/cf.sum(0))
recall_macro = np.nanmean(TP/cf.sum(1))

print("Calculated:")
print("precision_micro:", precision_micro)
print("precision_macro:", precision_macro)
print("recall_micro:", recall_micro)
print("recall_macro:", recall_macro)
```

```
Calculated:
precision_micro: 0.872125
precision_macro: 0.8702549015235986
recall_micro: 0.872125
recall_macro: 0.8696681555022805
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `scikit-learn` to calculate `recall` and `precision` of each class.

Example:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))

              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3

    accuracy                           0.60         5
   macro avg       0.50      0.56      0.49         5
weighted avg       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

Reference [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html)

Comment: If I don't have the y_true and y_pred values ready in txt file. What should I do to get them in txt file?

Comment: Hi, if you don't have the y_pred, you can use the trained model to inference them, but for the y_true, it must be within the dataset.